# How string length is printing more then size of char array, if give input more then char array?

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char s1[100];
    printf("Enter String \n");
    scanf("%s",s1);
    int i;
    for(i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++);
    printf("Length : %d \n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program i was trying to find length of the string. for that i created char array with size 100 but when i was giving input more  then lenght 100 still it is printing length upto 141 after that i am getting "stack smashing detected" error. how is it printing length more then 100?

Comment: Kudos, you just discovered **Undefined Behavior**! Now just Google it.

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this question around here on SO. The compiler will not stop you from shooting yourself in the foot, for example by writing out of bounds of an array.

Comment: Its undefined behaviour. Any way did you enter a space in your string input>

Comment: ya WhenI i gave space it printing string length till space only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, given you have defined your string as `char s1[100];`  limit the string input length of scanf by changing your format specifier from:

```
scanf("%s",s1);
```

to:

```
scanf("%99s",s1);// 99, + 1 for NULL terminator
```

***About buffer overflow***:
If you define a string, say:

```
char string[5];//holds 4 characters and a NULL terminator
```

In memory, it may look like this:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
                      |^ ^ ^ ^ ^| (Allocated space)
```

strcpy(string, "hold");
results in:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|h|o|l|d|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
                      |^ ^ ^ ^ ^| (Allocated space)
```

No problem, you have written to an area owned by your variable.

When you assign more than it should hold:

```
strcpy(string, "holds more...");
```

results in:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|h|o|l|d|s| |m|o|r|e|.|.|.|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
                      |^ ^ ^ ^ ^| (Allocated space)
```

If the contiguous areas of memory following the memory assigned to your buffer are empty, and currently unused/unclaimed by any other process at the time you write to them, then the act of writing to them will show no effect, i.e. It appears to "work", and ***printf(,,) works just fine*** printing the buffer.  But later, you may attempt to write to that same area and find you get an error.  This is an example of ***[undefined behavior](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior)***.

Here is more on ***[avoiding buffer overflow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html)***.

Comment: `char s1[100];` --> `scanf("%99s",s1);`.  In `scanf()`, 99 is the max width of input.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing [string overflow](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/String-overflows-with-scanf.html), you are filling the string with more characters that it can hold, in C it leads to undefined behavior.

Remember that you need to allocate n+1 (n = size of your string) to store the NULL-terminator value.
You can limit the number of chars to read in scanf, this way you prevent a string overflow.

i.e:

```
scanf("%99s",s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't do out of bounds checking. So writing and reading to locations beyond the array invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Anything can happen.